Error while trying to connect Django With ReactNative
I am building a React Native app with Django as the backend. I have set up the login screen in React Native and configured JWT authentication with rest_framework_simplejwt in Django. However, I encounter an error when trying to log in.
Within the login screen:
    const [username, setUsername] = useState("");
    const [password, setPassword] = useState("");
    const [error, setError] = useState("");

    const handleSubmission = async () => {
        try {
            const response = await axios.post("http://127.0.0.1:8080/api/token/", {
                username,
                password,
            });
            if (!response || !response.data) {
                throw new Error("Invalid server response");
            }
            await AsyncStorage.setItem("accessToken", response.data.access);
            await AsyncStorage.setItem("refreshToken", response.data.refresh);
            navigation.navigate("Tab");
        } catch (error) {
            console.error("error", error);
            const errorMessage = error.response && error.response.data && error.response.data.message
                ? error.response.data.message
                : "Whoops! Log In Failed, please try again later .";
            setError(errorMessage);
        }
    };

In Django, views:
@api_view(['POST'])
@permission_classes([IsAuthenticated])
def create_user(request):
    serializer = CreateUserSerializer(data=request.data)
    if serializer.is_valid():
        serializer.save()
        return Response(serializer.data, status=status.HTTP_201_CREATED)
    return Response({'message': "Whoops! error while creating user ", 'error': serializer.errors}, status=status.HTTP_400_BAD_REQUEST)

Serializers:
class CreateUserSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    class Meta:
        model = User
        fields = ['username', 'password']

    def create(self, validated_data):
        validated_data['password'] = make_password(validated_data.get('password'))
        return super(CreateUserSerializer, self).create(validated_data)

and I set up cors in settings.py so that I can make API request on my machine:
INSTALLED_APPS = [
    'corsheaders', # DEV ONLY
    ...
]

MIDDLEWARE = [
    'corsheaders.middleware.CorsMiddleware', # DEV ONLY
    ...
]

CORS_ALLOW_ALL_ORIGINS = True # DEV ONLY

The error I'm getting is:
LOG  error [TypeError: Cannot read property 'status' of undefined]
What I've tried:

Ensured corsheaders is installed and properly configured.
Verified that the backend endpoint http://127.0.0.1:8080/api/token/ is correct and reachable.
Logged the complete error object.

How can I resolve the TypeError: Cannot read property 'status' of undefined error and ensure that my login functionality works correctly?

To connect react native to django server, run the server on your ip instead of localhost. This assumes your ip is 10.0.0.49
python manage.py runserver 10.0.0.49:8000

Then change the frontend request to
const response = await axios.post("http://10.0.0.49:8080/api/token/", {
            username,
            password,
        });

I had this problem with my django rn project too a while back, very frustrating
